# ogr2ogr output missing some relations

Tags: openstreetmap, ogr2ogr, osmium

I'm trying to extract data from `planet.osm.pbf` with osmium and ogr2ogr as a CSV file. However some relations seem to be missing in the output. For example, [this relation](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/3492137) doesn't show up as a multipolygon.

I am using

```
osmium getid planet.osm.pbf r3492137 -r -o culver_city.pbf
```

and then

```
ogr2ogr -f "CSV" -lco SEPARATOR="TAB" -overwrite culver_city.csv ../culver_city.pbf
```

But the resulting `multipolygons.csv` is empty (without any error). The `lines.csv` seems to contain the ways that make up the relation.

The same thing seems to work properly for other relations like [this one](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/3353288). What could be wrong?

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/451365/why-do-certain-features-from-geofabriks-osm-extract-seem-to-be-missing

Answer (score 1):

This could be because those relations are not properly tagged as ***type=multipolygon*** in the OSM data. The ogr2ogr command only converts relations with this tag to multipolygons in the output file.

To fix the problem, double check that the missing relations are correctly tagged as ***type=multipolygon*** in the OSM data, if not, correct it and run the command again. If it still doesn't work, try using the ***-explodecollections*** option to see if the missing data is stored elsewhere in the data.