# Why do certain features from Geofabrik's OSM extract seem to be missing?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, overpass-api, quickosm, geofabrik

I would like to have all objects from OpenStreetMap with the [`Tag:man_made=works`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:man_made%3Dworks) (ie factories), in Estonia. I can do this using QGIS, but another method using GeoFabrik's OSM extract fails.

---

### QGIS way

I download Estonia's borders from [osm-boundaries.com](https://osm-boundaries.com/). I add it as a QGIS layer. Then I set up a query using the [QuickOSM](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickOSM/) plugin (Overpass API endpoint set as: `https://lz4.overpass-api.de/api/`, Nominatim API endpoint set as: `https://nominatim.qgis.org/search?`):

[image]

After `Run query`, I get several factories.

[image]

I can export these to GeoJSONs.

---

### OSM extract from GeoFabrik

I am trying to achieve the same thing via another way. I download `estonia-latest.osm.bz2` from http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/estonia.html:

```
curl https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/estonia-latest.osm.bz2 -o estonia-latest.osm.bz2
```

Uncompress file:

```
bzip2 -dk estonia-latest.osm.bz2 # produces estonia-latest.osm
```

As suggested by this answer as well, `estonia-latest.osm` has:

```
points
lines
multilinestrings
multipolygons
other_relations
```

(I know this by running: `ogrinfo estonia-latest.osm | tail -n +3 | awk '{print $2}'`)

Let's attempt to extract all `man_made=works`! I do:

```
for each in $(ogrinfo estonia-latest.osm | tail -n +3 | awk '{print $2}'); do
    rm -f factories_${each}.geojson
    echo ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON factories_${each}.geojson estonia-latest.osm $each -where "other_tags LIKE '%\"man_made\"=>\"works\"%'"
    # this line above^ is to check what ogr2ogr command is running
    ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON factories_${each}.geojson estonia-latest.osm $each -where "other_tags LIKE '%\"man_made\"=>\"works\"%'"
done
```

Output:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON factories_points.geojson estonia-latest.osm points -where other_tags LIKE '%"man_made"=>"works"%'
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON factories_lines.geojson estonia-latest.osm lines -where other_tags LIKE '%"man_made"=>"works"%'
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON factories_multilinestrings.geojson estonia-latest.osm multilinestrings -where other_tags LIKE '%"man_made"=>"works"%'
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON factories_multipolygons.geojson estonia-latest.osm multipolygons -where other_tags LIKE '%"man_made"=>"works"%'
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON factories_other_relations.geojson estonia-latest.osm other_relations -where other_tags LIKE '%"man_made"=>"works"%'
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

**Problem: all the files created** (`factories_points.geojson`, `factories_lines.geojson`, `factories_multilinestrings.geojson`, `factories_multipolygons.geojson`, `factories_other_relations.geojson`) **are empty**.

If I replace the `where` clause by `"other_tags LIKE '%\"power\"=>\"substation\"%'"`, I do indeed get many [electrical substations](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:power%3Dsubstation).

---

The query for factories might be wrong. GeoFabrik's OSM extract might not contain the factories I am looking for. Or something else.

### What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man_made` is an important tag that has its own field, so you can query it directly:

`ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON factories_${each}.geojson estonia-latest.osm $each -where "man_made='works'"`

The fields that will get into their own column is an ogr2ogr [configuration](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/osm.html#configuration) (`osmconf.ini` located in GDAL data folder), whose defaults can be seen [here](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/osm/data/osmconf.ini).

At time of writing (02/2023) they are:

points: `name, barrier, highway, ref, address, is_in, place, man_made`
lines: `name, highway, waterway, aerialway, barrier, man_made, railway`
multi lines: `name, type`
multi polygons: `name, type, aeroway, amenity, admin_level, barrier, boundary, building, craft, geological, historic, land_area, landuse, leisure, man_made, military, natural, office, place, shop, sport, tourism`
other: `name, type`